# ApiResource routes returning 404 after upgrading Symfony from 5.4 to 6.1

Tags: php, symfony, api-platform.com

After upgrading Symfony from 5.4 to 6.1, our ApiResource routes are not found. I have api-platform/core 2.7.

Here are our routes:

Symfony 5.4

```
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------- ---------- -------- ------ ------------------------------------------------------------
  Name                                                                   Method     Scheme   Host   Path
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------- ---------- -------- ------ ------------------------------------------------------------
  ...
  default                                                                ANY        ANY      ANY    /
  api_genid                                                              ANY        ANY      ANY    /.well-known/genid/{id}
  api_entrypoint                                                         ANY        ANY      ANY    /{index}.{_format}
  api_doc                                                                ANY        ANY      ANY    /docs.{_format}
  api_jsonld_context                                                     ANY        ANY      ANY    /contexts/{shortName}.{_format}
  api_gift_card_solutions_incoming_order_item_webhooks_post_collection   POST       ANY      ANY    /incoming-webhooks/gift-card-solutions/orders
  api_images_get_collection                                              GET        ANY      ANY    /images.{_format}
  api_images_get_item                                                    GET        ANY      ANY    /images/{id}.{_format}
  api_orders_post_collection                                             POST       ANY      ANY    /orders.{_format}
  api_orders_get_item                                                    GET        ANY      ANY    /orders/{id}.{_format}
  api_payment_gateway_incoming_order_intent_webhooks_post_collection     POST       ANY      ANY    /incoming-webhooks/payment-gateway/order-intents
  api_products_get_collection                                            GET        ANY      ANY    /products.{_format}
  api_products_get_item                                                  GET        ANY      ANY    /products/{id}.{_format}
  api_settings_get_collection                                            GET        ANY      ANY    /settings.{_format}
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------- ---------- -------- ------ ------------------------------------------------------------
```

Symfony 6.1

```
 ----------------------------------------------- ---------- -------- ------ ------------------------------------------------------------
  Name                                            Method     Scheme   Host   Path
 ----------------------------------------------- ---------- -------- ------ ------------------------------------------------------------
  ...
  default                                         ANY        ANY      ANY    /
  api_genid                                       ANY        ANY      ANY    /.well-known/genid/{id}
  api_entrypoint                                  ANY        ANY      ANY    /{index}.{_format}
  api_doc                                         ANY        ANY      ANY    /docs.{_format}
  api_jsonld_context                              ANY        ANY      ANY    /contexts/{shortName}.{_format}
 ----------------------------------------------- ---------- -------- ------ ------------------------------------------------------------
```

This is one of our ApiResource: Order.php

```
...
#[ApiResource(
    collectionOperations: [
        'get' => [
            'security' => "is_granted(permission('IMAGE_LIST'), object)",
        ],
    ],
    itemOperations: [
        'get' => [
            'security' => "is_granted(permission('IMAGE_READ'), object)",
        ],
    ],
    normalizationContext: ['groups' => ['image:read', 'timestamp:read', 'primary_key:read']],
)]
...
#[ORM\Entity]
#[ORM\Table(name: 'images')]
class Image extends AbstractDatabaseEntity implements ActivatableEntityInterface, ProviderAwareInterface
{
...
```

Here is the response:
[image]

For the upgrade, fixed all deprecations using rector and everything. We also have a different project and proceed with the same upgrade steps.

Answer (score 2):

You have upgraded your code from using `Annotations` to [`Attributes`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.attributes.overview.php). API Platform v2.7 does not support `Attributes` straight out of the box, it works with `Annotations`. Either upgrade to API Platform `^3.0` or if you want to keep using v2.7 use the backwards compatability config options:

```
api_platform:
   metadata_backward_compatibility_layer: false
```

This is needed in v2.7 to use the new metadata system, since the default value is true.

See more details here : [Upgrade guide](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/upgrade-guide/)

Comment: Isn't it weird that I already have API Platform v2.7 when it was just Symfony 5.4... And the only thing I upgraded was the Symfony to v6.1

Comment: You did not just only upgrade Symfony, you also instructed Rector to move from Annotations (PHP7) to using Attributes (PHP8). This caused the issue, not the Symfony upgrade.

Comment: I apologize for the late response. I overlooked the config, I thought last day that 2.7's default value for `metadata_backward_compatibility_layer` was already false. But I'm still having the 404 issues.

Comment: Just to share, my lead fixed the issue by using Symfony 6.3 and upgrading some of the composer packages. But thanks for checking into my question!